# Do we need the [fortress] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The recently-created [fortress](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fortress) tag is applied to only one [question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9503/how-do-i-set-up-a-political-conflict-in-this-large-city) so far. However, it seems it me to be fairly meta: all I can tell from this tag is that there is somehow a fortress involved in the questions: not who lives there, what is happening to it, or how it's built; not how it relates to the world in question or the question in the world.

What do we think? Is it necessary? Its easy enough to clean it up if we decide we don't now, just removing it from the question will see it automatically deleted.

Comment: Might be better as [tag:fortification]?

Comment: @TimB I don't think we need it at all

Comment: Seems a little too specific, surely it will almost never be used? does the defeat the point of tags?

Comment: The tag is ok by itself but the question doesn't need that tag.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we need it.  We already have [city-design](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/city-design) and [military-defense](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/military-defense), which used *together* say "fortress/fortifications" to me -- though in the case of this question its "fort-ness" isn't obviously central anyway.  If a body of questions develops then the tag's unique properties should become apparent, at which point they can be captured in a tag wiki.

Comment: Sorry, I was too fast : http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9503/how-do-i-set-up-a-political-conflict-in-this-large-city

Comment: @Vincent thanks for adding the link to the question.